# Openssl RSA key PEM and DER conversion - does not match

Tags: openssl, rsa

I am studying openssl with the RSA key generation and manipulation. First I generated a key pair encoded in PEM format but unencrypted:

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out key.pem -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048
```

Then I converted to DER format:

```
openssl rsa -inform PEM -outform DER -in key.pem -out key1.cer
```

Then I converted it back to PEM encoded:

```
openssl rsa -inform DER -outform PEM -in key1.cer -out key2.pem
```

Now if I compare the two, they are different in their contents (BASE64 encoded texts). The size of the files are different too...

```
diff key.pem key2.pem
```

Why is that? Did I do something wrong here?

All the keys are attached here.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ec1sm3y63sahwks/AAB6At3x_j5LRyf63gJDJn39a?dl=0

Thanks,
Difan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the PEM files and you will see one begins with `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` and the other begins with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`. The words in the BEGIN and END lines of a PEM block specify the format of the data in the block, and these specify two of about 10 (depending exactly how you count) **different data formats** supported by OpenSSL for RSA keys.

The first one is the **unencrypted variant of PKCS8** [republished as RFC 5208](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5208) at section 5. PKCS8 can handle private keys for many different algorithms, including RSA DSA DH and ECDSA, with or without password-based encryption (PBE) of the key. `openssl genpkey` is designed to handle multiple algorithms and uses the PKCS8 format to do so.

The second one is the RSA-only **privatekey syntax of PKCS1** [republished as RFC3447](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#appendix-A.1) et pred in section A.1. This format is written by the older `openssl rsa` and `openssl genrsa` functions because they handle only RSA, and is called the 'tradtional' or 'legacy' format to distinguish it from PKCS8. PKCS1 does not define any encrypted format, but OpenSSL supports a generic PEM-encryption scheme that can be applied to this format if requested which you did not. However, the OpenSSL 'legacy' PEM encryption is not as good as that used in PKCS8, so you should normally use PKCS8 if you want security, or possibly PKCS12 instead for a privatekey *with certificates*.

You can convert to *PKCS8* DER and back to PEM using `pkey` which like `genpkey` handles multiple algorithms and uses PKCS8:

```
openssl pkey -in key.pem [-inform PEM] -out key.der -outform DER 
openssl pkey -in key.der -inform DER -out xxx.pem [-outform PEM]
# now xxx.pem is the same as key.pem
```

Since PEM files (unlike DER) can be recognized by the type in the BEGIN line, you can convert PKCS1 PEM back to PKCS8 directly:

```
openssl pkey -in key2.pem -out yyy.pem 
# now yyy.pem is the same as key.pem
```

Programs using the OpenSSL library, including but not limited to `openssl` commandline, can read a privatekey PEM file in either of these formats automatically, and also either of the two encrypted formats automatically if the correct password is provided.

Comment: Thank you sir! Very clear answer. I upvoted however apparently that I am new with low reputation so my upvote does not count... Sorry.. But this answer should attract some upvotes!